# Make input field populate with today's date when user clicks on the select option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-state

When the user clicks the option value "apple" for example, the input field should automatically populate with today's date.

Here's my code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, {useState} from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [selectedFruit, setSelectedFruit] = useState('orange')
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e)=>{
    if(selectedFruit === "apple"){
      setValue(new Date(e.target.value));
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <select
      value={selectedFruit}
      onChange={e => setSelectedFruit(e.target.value)}
    >
      <option value="apple">Apple</option>
      <option value="banana">Banana</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried setting the state of the input field to match the value of the select option value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set type to 'date' or 'datetime-local'